# Google Sheets Select X where (max(y)<=z)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

my title is potentially not that enticing. But I am trying to create a semi-dynamic formula in order to find a "stock on hand" up to a particular date in time. There is a set number of locations ids 1-10, and two product types 3 & 4.
It is not guaranteed that each location will have a stock count at the date in question. I want to use query to find THE MOST RECENT stock count where location and product type and <= date
here is the basic formula
`=QUERY(Sheet1!A160:E3530,"SELECT D WHERE ((B = "&$H$1&")) AND (E <= date '"&TEXT(MAX($M$3),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') AND ((A = "&G2&"))", true)`
But I need to figure out how to use MAX to find the most recent date within the date range specified.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT 23/06/2021

You will note this is a fraction of the data I have in my set (in the example sheet), so most numbers show as zero, but the formula

=MAXIFS($C$3:$C$6040,$A$3:$A$6040,I3,$B$3:$B$6040,$J$2,$E$3:$E$6040,(MAX(QUERY($A$3:$E$6040,"SELECT E WHERE (E <= date '"&TEXT($R$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"') AND ((A = "&I3&")) AND ((B = "&$J$2&"))", true))))

works on my full data. So this finds the most recent record of equipment type 3 or 4, up to the specified date and from a specified yard. Further filtering is done based on a change type of "converted, removed,dead,added,etc". What I want to do now is do a monthly or fortnightly line chart over time, eg the 14th and 29th of each month, or the 20th of each month and plot the the sum of each column J:Q. To start I hoped to use the date in U:U and populate the V:AC accordingly.

I have played with the onEvent script but I am struggling to make progess here

Comment: MAX(QUERY(...)) did not work?

Comment: Here's a blank sheet.  Paste some sample data in order to explain the question better.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iuHS-RshUZo1tzX1-vVhHtdYiQBTCFGqVWA0zG0Qr-Y/edit

Comment: Thank you for the sample sheet. I have put in a portion of data and used comment to try and explain the fields. Essentially I want to set a target date and then have the fields populate the most current count of an equipment type belonging to each yard ID.

Comment: @JeremyKahan no, I did try this but it would simply return the highest total count up to the date but not the most recent count.

Comment: In 2018-06-01 have 2 entries.. which value to be taken as answer for Equipment 3?

Comment: Ok - I have figured out the answer to my orignal question. I now have a range of data in J:Q which dynamically updates based on the date selected in R2.